# Check Input in Visual C++ using C commands

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to use the following code just to check the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() 
  {
    int number1; 

    puts("Enter number 1 please:");
    scanf_s("%d",&number1);

    if (isdigit(number1)) 
    {
      puts("Input is correct.");

    }
    else 
    {
      puts("Your input is not correct. Enter a number please.");
    }

      std::cin.get();
      std::cin.get();


  }
```

Unfortunately it doensn't work. I type in a digit and my response is "Your input is not...". Any suggestions where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the use of isdigit. Compare this code:

```
int main() 
{
int number1; 

puts("Enter number 1 please:");
scanf_s("%d",&number1);
printf("You entered %d\n", number1);
if (isdigit(number1)) 
{
  puts("Input is correct.");

}
else 
{
  puts("Your input is not correct. Enter a number please.");
}

  std::cin.get();
  std::cin.get();


}
```

When you enter a valid number, this is reflected in the successful printf of this number.

You should check the return of scanf, not use isdigit, such as this sample code:

```
int main() 
{
int number1; 

puts("Enter number 1 please:");
if (scanf_s("%d",&number1))        
  puts("Input is correct.");
else
  puts("Your input is not correct. Enter a number please.");

std::cin.get();
std::cin.get();
}
```

I believe that for more than one field, you will need to check the return value of scanf more closely than simply zero or one.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is definetly smarter than mine.

Answer (score 0):

isdigit accepts number1 of type char and not int. 
Replacing number1 to be of type char will solve the problem and report correct results.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I changed int number1 in char number1, but i still have the same problem.

Comment: You also need to change %d and make it to %c